# Hiding apps from users

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a question about adding SharePoint apps:

Is it possible to hide an installed/added app (in a site collection) from users with specific permissions or from a user group?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the app to a specific site collection but, I am afraid what you are looking for may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Sharepoint groups/permissions and the Sharepoint apps/permissions are both at different level. An app for SharePoint has its own identity and is associated with a security principal, called an app principal. Like users and groups, an app principal has certain permissions and rights. The app principal has full control rights to the app web so it only needs to request permissions to SharePoint resources in the host web or other locations outside the app web.

Important Refer:
[Use SharePoint permission management to create various roles in an app for SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/09/25/use-sharepoint-permission-management-to-create-various-roles-in-an-app-for-sharepoint.aspx)

Also Refer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383(v=office.15).aspx#Perm_manage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179922(v=office.15).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219576(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: The problem is not so much providing the app with the needed permissions to access the necessary SharePoint resources as allowing who can use your app. So this involves a user/group permission outside the app.

Comment: @UserSP You are not answering the question. The question is whether it is possible to hide apps from a set of users, or to make them available only to a set of users.

Answer (score 0):

***Simply way***

Directly you can go to list/library setting in the ribbon and assign permissions.

**Or else**

- Go to site content and click on three dots(`...`) for more information on top of the app.
- Next step click setting
- In settings page, you can see `Permissions for this list/library.`
- There first click `Stop Inheriting Permission` in ribbon. Then you can assign the permissions in the permission levels, and you can hide the app/add-in for specific users and also you can add a group user.

For more reference [Hiding SharePoint Apps/Add-ins from users](https://blog.sprider.org/2016/01/28/hiding-sharepoint-appsadd-ins-from-users/)

Answer (score 0):

We have some commercial apps that we are testing that we cannot hide. This is causing issues as people are trying to install them, and are asking why they cannot. We need to be able to hide them, but they do not appear in the App Catalog. The only workaround we have at the moment is to use a Custom Action to hide using CSS. Works but not ideal.

Comment: You cannot add your comments as answer,understand that you cannot comment now unless you gain enough reputation.  so explore SE by clicking here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour and start contributing.

Answer (score 0):

You can regrant permissions to an add-in by using the following steps:

1. On the Site Contents page of the website where the add-in seems to have lost permissions, select the ??? button on the add-in's tile. This opens a callout with either a PERMISSIONS link or another ??? button.
2. Select the PERMISSIONS link if it is there and skip the next step, or select the ??? button.
3. Select the Permissions link.
4. On the page that opens, select here in the last sentence. This regrants the add-in its permissions and redirects the browser back to the Site Contents page.

Answer (score -1):

Not ideal but use some jQuery to hide it, e.g.

```
jQuery('img[alt="YourAppTitle"]').closest('div[class^="ms-vl-apptile"]').hide();
```